# 'software-properties-gtk' not opening in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: updates, software-center, update-manager, gtk, 21.04

Recently I updated to Ubuntu 21.04 from 20.10. After the update was complete for few days it was all okay. I was getting system update notification and security updates etc. But few days back I was thinking of updating my system and tried opening 'Software & updates' (I know this doesn't updates system please read ahead) but my bad I mistakenly clicked it so again from Applications list I clicked 'Software Updater' and there was no updates I thought something might be wrong and I clicked settings button then a prompt came up saying to report I was confused then I realized that it was `software-properties-gtk` which is causing this problem and not giving me system update notification and etc. Then in terminal I typed `sudo software-properties-gtk` and this was the output I got:

```
lmao@lol:~$ sudo software-properties-gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 177, in activate_name_owner
    return self.get_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 361, in get_name_owner
    return self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties': no such name

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 197, in __init__
    proxy = bus.get_object("com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties", "/")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    return self.ProxyObjectClass(self, bus_name, object_path,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 250, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 182, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 277, in start_service_by_name
    return (True, self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
```

Please don't mark this problem duplicate of [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236593/software-properties-gtk-does-not-start). Because [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236593/software-properties-gtk-does-not-start) had `File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py"` problem but mine is `File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py"`. Please help me fix this issue editing repos from terminal is kinda hard job for me so I was having great days using this as repository editor. (Not fully I always use terminal for adding them and just use `software-properties-gtk` to disable that.)

Comment: This answer is equally valid for your issue: https://askubuntu.com/a/236609/1210606. You can edit repositories at Software & Updates and you should run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` to make sure your system is fully updated.

Comment: I was trying to open `software-properties-gtk` for editing repository list. Editing repository list requires me to open `software-properties-gtk` this was the issue whole time.